# Closing Colorbox after a delay

Tags: jquery, colorbox, delay

I would like to close the (iframe) colorbox I've opened after a submit after a delay. the following js line is not working:

```
 parent.$.colorbox.delay(500).close();
```

Does anyone know how to close the colorbox after a delay?

Comment: try http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)?

```
setTimeout(parent.$.colorbox.close, 500);
```

Comment: This works... is it also possible to refresh the parent page after closing the colorbox?

Comment: @Stefan probably have already found it some years ago, but here's for newcomers - just slightly changed David's example: setTimeout(function() {
                parent.$.colorbox.close;
                parent.location.reload();
            }, 500);

Answer (score 2):

try reading the first 3 answers :D :D

(sorry, couldn't resist)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // close colorbox
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using setTimeout:

```
var box = parent.$.colorbox;
setTimeout(function(){
    box.close();
}, 500);
```